# Is there a Totally Ordered Set which the only order-isomorphism to itself is the Identity? And the set and its inverse are not well ordered

Tags: order-theory

the inverse set of $\ \left(A,<\right) $  is $\ \left(A,<^{-1}\right) $ with $\ a<^{-1}b\iff b<a$

the set and its inverse **are not well ordered**

Comment: You've edited the question like you've *not* read the duplicate one.